Avoid the blank screen coming up for a fraction of second
I’m working on a nested menu component, and while the functionality is working as expected, I’m facing an issue with the transitions. When I click on a menu item to view its sub-items, there’s a blank screen that briefly appears before the transition occurs. I can’t figure out what’s causing this flicker. Any suggestions?


const { useState}  = React;
const data=[
  {
    "c_addressRegionAbbreviation": "Montana",
    "dm_directoryChildren": [
      {
        "dm_directoryChildren": [
          {
            "id": "Bank1",
            "name": "Elkwood",
            "coordinate": {
              "latitude": 38.5124137,
              "longitude": -77.8548617
            }
          }
        ],
        "id": "fins-locations-directory_mt_elkwood",
        "name": "Elkwood",
        "slug": "mt/elkwood"
      },
      {
        "dm_directoryChildren": [
          {
            "id": "Bank2",
            "name": "Stonebridge",
            "coordinate": {
              "latitude": 46.8796822,
              "longitude": -110.3625658
            }
          }
        ],
        "id": "fins-locations-directory_mt_stonebridge",
        "name": "Stonebridge",
        "slug": "mt/stonebridge"
      }
    ],
    "id": "fins-locations-directory_mt",
    "name": "MT",
    "slug": "mt"
  },
  {
    "c_addressRegionAbbreviation": "Illinois",
    "dm_directoryChildren": [
      {
        "dm_directoryChildren": [
          {
            "id": "Dummy-771676",
            "name": "Chicago",
            "coordinate": {
              "latitude": 41.90323,
              "longitude": -87.62924
            }
          }
        ],
        "id": "fins-locations-directory_il_chicago",
        "name": "Chicago",
        "slug": "il/chicago"
      }
    ],
    "id": "fins-locations-directory_il",
    "name": "IL",
    "slug": "il"
  }
];

const Example = ({ title }) => {
    const [currList, setCurrList] =
    useState(data);
  const [prevList, setPrevList] = useState(null);
  const [isTransitioning, setIsTransitioning] = useState(false);

  const handleFilter = (currentId: string) => {
    const newList = currList.find((item) => item.id === currentId);
    if (newList && newList.dm_directoryChildren) {
      setIsTransitioning(true);
      setPrevList(currList);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setCurrList(newList.dm_directoryChildren);
        setPrevList(null);
        setIsTransitioning(false);
      }, 300);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <article className="mt-28 mx-auto h-[800px] flex overflow-hidden">
        <div className="w-[400px] overflow-hidden">
          <ul className="absolute top-0 left-0 z-50 flex flex-col h-full w-full bg-slate-100"> 
          {currList.map((item, index) => (
              <li
                onClick={() => handleFilter(item.id)}
                key={`curr-${index}`}
                className={`flex justify-between border-skin-base border-b last:border-b-0 py-4 px-2 transition-transform duration-300 ${
                  isTransitioning
                    ? "translate-x-full opacity-0"
                    : "translate-x-0 opacity-100"
                }`}
              >
                {item.c_addressRegionAbbreviation || item.name}
               </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </article>
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Example title="Example using Hooks:" />
);
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script>
  tailwind.config = {
    theme: {
      extend: {
        colors: {
          clifford: '#da373d',
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>



Thanks
